# Spring config didn't work as expected

Tags: java, spring

I'm building a new project, and I thought I'd try a new way of loading my Spring config. I found the `@Configuration` annotation and decided to give it a try.

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:myApp-config.xml")
public class MyAppConfig
{
    @Autowired
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Bean(name="someOtherBeanName")
    public MyClass getMyClass ()
    {
        return myClass;
    }

    public void setMyClass( myClass m)
    {
        this.myClass= m;
    }
}
```

In the spring config file:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<bean name="someOtherBeanName" class="com.MyClass">
    <property name="myClass">
        <map>
            <!-- details not relevant -->
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

To make use of this, I have code like this:

```
//class member
private static MyAppConfig cfg = new MyAppConfig();
...
...
...
//In the class that needs the configuration
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
ctx.register(MyAppConfig.class);
ctx.refresh();
//appMgr = cfg.getMyClass();
appMgr = (MyClass) ctx.getBean("someOtherBeanName");
```

As you can see, I'd thought I could get a spring-configured instances of MyClass from my configuration object, but instead I had to get it from my context object.

I guess I misunderstood the way `@Configuration` and `@Bean` work. Am I pretty close or way off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get your bean from `cfg.getMyClass();`, there are some misunderstanding.

`@Configuration` is only another representation of spring configuration, you should understand it just like your `application-context.xml`, nothing is new here.

Comment: Depends what you mean. If OP had gotten the `cfg` object from the `ctx`, then, yes, they can use `cfg.getMyClass()` to get the bean.

Comment: You're right, I was misunderstanding how to use `@Configuration` - I was thinking I could use it as an easier way to load my config, not that it *was* my config.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
private static MyAppConfig cfg = new MyAppConfig();
```

is not a **Spring managed bean** so you will get `null` when calling `getMyClass()`.

Also, the following

```
@ImportResource("classpath:myApp-config.xml")
```

with

```
@Autowired
private MyClass myClass;

@Bean(name="someOtherBeanName")
public MyClass getMyClass ()
{
    return myClass;
}
```

is redundant. Because of the `@ImportResource`, the bean from the XML configuration is already in the context.

> Indicates one or more resources containing bean definitions to import.

You don't need an additional `@Bean` method in between.

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty way off... going full Java-based config will be for your example:

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyClass someOtherBeanName() {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.setMyProp(null /* details not relevant */);
        return myClass;
    }

}
```

---

Somewhere else in the `main` method (this is unchanged):

```
//In the class that needs the configuration
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
ctx.register(MyAppConfig.class);
ctx.refresh();
//appMgr = cfg.getMyClass();
appMgr = (MyClass) ctx.getBean("someOtherBeanName");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add something that you might meet, if u still can not find config.xml or javaconfig.class. Check your file structure.

> - **src**
>
>   - **config.xml** or **javaconfig.java**

To save your config in your path(default package is src)